# JS Как сделать так, чтобы элементы объектов не ссылались в одно и то же место?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть исходный объект c массивом `obj = {res: [ {...}, {...} ... {...} ] }`

Этот массив присваиваю двум другим массивам, один буду менять, другой нет.

```
constArr = [...obj.res]
letArr = [...constArr]
```

Потом, если менять значения объектов внутри letArr так же меняются значения внутри constArr

Как этого избежать?

Comment: нужно клонировать объекты, если они в свою очередь не содержат ссылок на другие объекты, вполне подойдет `let clone ={}; Object.assign( clone, {...})`, так же есть такой фокус , хоть и медленный : `let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({...}))`

Answer (score -1):

```
var copyOfMyArray = myArray.slice(0);
```

slice(0) создаст копию myArray и таким образом не будет изменения по ссылке

Comment: вопрос про другое...

Comment: slice не сделает копию вложенных объектов, а сохранит ссылки. для глубокого копирования, можно использовать метод cloneDeep у lodash или clone у Ramda